# IOS Swift - Get values from different nodes in Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nodes

I'd like to get the list of participants of an event, in the **events** node, only the id# of the employee is listed. What I would like to achieve is get the name associated to that id # from the **Employee** node. Here's the structure of my dbase.

```
events:
     uuid:
        name: summer festival 2017
        site: vegas
        participants:
           employeeID1: true
           employeeID2: true 

Employee:
    employeeID1:
       name: gary
       department: video production
```

and here's my code

```
@IBAction func downloadButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

      ref.child("events").child(eventKeyLabel.text!).child("participants").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            // get the dictionary from the snapshot
            if let participantsDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {


                for each in participantsDict {

                    let employeeIDNum = each.key
                    let employeeName = self.getName(forUID: employeeIDNum)

                    self.employeeID.append(employeeIDNum)
                    self.name.append(employeeName)

                }

              print(self.employeeID)
              print(self.name)

            }

        }) // End observeSingleEvent

    }


    func getName(forUID userID: String) -> String{

        var empName = ""

        ref.child("Employee").child(userID).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

                empName = (value["name"] as? String)!
            }
        })

       return empName
    }
```

Results:

```
["0001", "0002", "0003", "0004"]
["", "", "", ""]
```

**FULL CODE:**

@IBAction func downloadButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
ref.child("events").child(eventKeyLabel.text!).child("participants").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

    // get the dictionary from the snapshot
    if let participantsDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {


        for each in participantsDict {

            let employeeIDNum = each.key
            self.getName(forUID: employeeIDNum) { empName in
                self.name.append(empName)
                print(empName)
            }

            self.employeeID.append(employeeIDNum)


        }

        print(self.employeeID)
        print(self.name)

    }

}) // End observeSingleEvent
```

}

func getName(forUID userID: String, callback: @escaping (String)->Void){

```
ref.child("Employee").child(userID).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
        print(value)
        if let empName = value["name"] as? String{
            callback(empName)
        }
    }
})
```

}

It doesn't return the employee names. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Please check that by adding print(empName) after empName = (value["name"] as? String)! statement inside getName function to see if empName exists here

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I did try it and it returned the name, however it crashes after it prints the name. it prints it but doesn't return it

Comment: Please check my answer, see if it helps, if you face problem, ask in comments

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this out. I'll let you know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that since this fetching from firebase is an asynchronous call, so you have to use callback to get the name to the function where you are calling the getName method, you can do something like this:

```
@IBAction func downloadButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

      ref.child("events").child(eventKeyLabel.text!).child("participants").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            // get the dictionary from the snapshot
            if let participantsDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {


                for each in participantsDict {

                    let employeeIDNum = each.key
                    self.getName(forUID: employeeIDNum)

                    self.employeeID.append(employeeIDNum)


                }

              print(self.employeeID)
              print(self.name)

            }

        }) // End observeSingleEvent

    }


    func getName(forUID userID: String) {



        ref.child("Employee").child(userID).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                print(value) //add here
                if let empName = value["name"] as? String{
                       self.name.append(empName)

                }
            }
        })


    }
```

Comment: it prints all the names when put print(self.name) below print(empName) so i guess it's appended to the name array, i'll have to double check. actually when the button is clicked it should loop through all the participants data and convert it to excel file and send it to email instead of displaying it to UITableView

Comment: Hello, I found out there's nothing wrong with my code after all. The problem was the : on the key names. I can now download the list of participants in csv format and send it to email. I couldn't have done it without your help, so thank you so much!

Comment: @TSM I am glad that I could help, congrats, I hope you have learnt about async and sync calls, callbacks etc please learn about these topics, these are important topics in ios development, Happy Coding :)